# ABC vs typing: is it possible to make a parameter truly optional?

Tags: python, python-typing, abc

With the following code, type checkers like `pylance` or `mypy` will complain about argument count mismatch (base `request` method has 3, but override only 2):

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from typing import TypedDict, Optional

class QueryParams(TypedDict):
    param_name: str
    param_value: str

class ApiClient(ABC):

    @abstractmethod
    def request(self, url: str, query_params: Optional[QueryParams] = None) -> None:
        raise NotImplementedError

class ConcreteApiClient(ApiClient):
    def request(self, url: str):
        print("I don't need query params to make request!")
```

It forces me to add the missing param:

```
class ConcreteApiClient(ApiClient):
    def request(self, url: str, query_params: Optional[QueryParams] = None):
        print("I don't need query params to make request!")
```

but such design is far from perfect since the param is never used.

I think I understand why it has to be like this (Liskov substitution principle).

Still, would the only way to improve this code be to make the subclasses define additional arguments they need, and stick only to non-None ones in the base class?

(So I guess by "truly" optional I mean: not having to include this param in function signature at all; with `Optional` I still need to write it, with `None` as default)

Comment: Would omitting `query_params` really be a good thing? It's important information

Comment: waht about interface segregation? that is create 2 abstract classes those that need the etra argument and those that not

Comment: Do you really need to define an ABC? I.e. does it provide you with anything that duck-typing doesn't?

Comment: @Lucas M. Uriarte: yes, that is a solution. I was just curious if this can be avoided, even though it probably shouldn't.

Comment: @joel The use case is that specific api client does not need `query_params` to fetch stuff, others do.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can get around `pylance` and `mypy` complaining here. And it makes sense, suppose you have the following code:

```
foo: ApiClient = ConcreteApiClient()

foo.request("https://www.example.com", {param_name: "my_param", param_value: "my_value"})
```

`mypy` and `pylance` will be perfectly happy with that code, as `ApiClient.request` accepts a second parameter and `ConcreteApiClient` inherits from `ApiClient`.

*Edit*: `pylance` won't actually be happy. It won't let you even assign a `ConcreteApiClient` to a field that's annotated just `ApiClient` as the methods aren't compatible. But not being able to assign a sub-class to a field of type super-class is a weird quirk and kinda unexpected. -- *Edit end* --

But when you execute that code you'll get a `TypeError` cause you passed too many arguments.

For this reason you shouldn't do this and that's also why the tools complain.

If you really want to force this you can just disable the checker for that line though:

```
class ConcreteApiClient(ApiClient):
    def request(self, url: str): # type: ignore
        print("I don't need query params to make request!")
```

Defining two interfaces is probably the best idea though:

```
class ApiClient(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def request(self, url: str) -> None:
        raise NotImplementedError

class ApiClientWithParams(ApiClient):

    @abstractmethod
    def request(self, url: str, query_params: Optional[QueryParams] = None) -> None:
        raise NotImplementedError

class ConcreteApiClient(ApiClient):
    def request(self, url: str):
        print("I don't need query params to make request!")
```

Adding additional **optional** parameters should be possible. But you always need to be able to call methods of subclasses with the signature of these methods in the superclass - if you cannot your type annotations are basically lying.

*Edit*: To answer the question if it's possible to make a parameter truly optional - depending on what truly optional should even mean.

On caller side: Yes

When inheriting: No, the only thing you can do is not using the param - or just digesting all extra params with `*args, **kwargs`. If you'd really want to achieve the goal of 'don't write a parameter that I don't use, my superclass has defined though' you'd need some quite dirty decorator magic, to add the missing parameters to the signature dynamically. The problem basically comes from that, that python won't call a function if there are too many arguments passed to that function, it doesn't just omit them...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I hate to nitpick, but re: "mypy and pylance will be perfectly happy with that code" - that is not really the case for me (`pylance` in strict mode expects 1 argument; it also highlights `request` methods as incompatible).

Comment: Oh - my bad... well in that case `pylance` is more powerful than expected. But not being able to assign a sub-class to a type of the superclass still shouldn't be. I'll make an edit